# lambda type deduction failure

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Would anybody like to explain why this code is incorrect for template functions but works well for ordinary function. For instance, if we replace `std::copy` with non-template functions, no problem.

How to change the code and make it valid for both template and non-template functions?

```
auto functionSpan = [](auto&& func, auto&&... args) {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
};

vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
functionSpan(std::copy, vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: `functionSpan([&]{ std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); });`

Answer (score 1):

std::copy does not refer to a single function. You need to specify `std::copy<Type>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `std::copy` (and really, *any* `template` function) isn't a regular function, so the compiler can't derive it.  What the compiler needs is a real function, although you could stamp out the the arguments to `std::copy`.

The issue with explicitly stamping out the arguments is your code isn't generic anymore, plus it's tedious and error-prone when dealing with iterators.  Instead, I'd suggest changing your function signatures a bit:

```
auto functionSpan = [](auto&& fn) {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    fn();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
};

auto copy_helper = [](auto && ... args) {
    return [args...]() {
        std::copy(args...);
    };
};

std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
functionSpan(copy_helper(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                         std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
                        ));
```

This compiles for me (I removed the `forward`ing to make my life simpler) and runs as expected.  You'll have to write a specific helper for each `template` function, but it's less boilerplate than trying to stamp out the `template` arguments since you still get most of the type deduction.